# Solving $3^x \cdot 4^{2x+1}=6^{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Find the exact value of $x$ for the equation $(3^x)(4^{2x+1})=6^{x+2}$

Give your answer in the form $\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$ where a and b are integers.

I have tried using a substitution method, i.e. putting $2^2$ to be $y$, but I have ended up with a complicated equation that hasn't put me any closer to the solution in correct form. Any hints or guidance are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\color{violet}{(3^x)(4^{2x+1})=6^{x+2}}$$
$$\color{indigo}{3^x\cdot 2^{2(2x+1)}=2^{x+2}\cdot 3^{x+2}}$$
$$\color{blue}{2^{2(2x+1)}\cdot 3^x=2^{x+2}\cdot 3^{x+2}}$$
$$\color{green}{\frac{2^{2(2x+1)}}{2^{x+2}}=\frac{3^{x+2}}{3^x}}$$
$$\color{brown}{2^{2(2x+1)-(x+2)}=3^{(x+2)-x}}$$
$$\color{orange}{2^{3x}=3^2}$$
$$\color{red}{8^x=9}$$
Taking natural logarithm on both sides, we get
$$\ln 8^x= \ln 9$$
$$\color{blue}{x=\frac{\ln 9}{\ln 8}}$$

To be a bit more precise i.e. simplifying a bit more we can have,
$$\color{red}{x=\frac{2\ln 3}{3\ln 2}}$$

Comment: Colorful answer!!

Comment: That yellow one is a bit hard to read....

Comment: @tatan Thanks for the edit.. I was running out of choices..

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Ha Ha!!!

Comment: Just one question here. Doesn't it violate the Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic? Every number is expressible as the powers of primes in only one way, right? It means that the coefficient of $3$ should match and the coefficient of $2$ should match. But, $x \neq x+2 \implies$ there is no solution, right ?

Comment: Or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @user230452 The Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic holds for integers only. But is $x$ an integer? Do you get the point?

Comment: I guess even the number $6^{x+2}$ is not an integer which is why the Theorem can't be applied. Always good to see the boundaries and limiting cases of theorems. Thanks!

Comment: @user230452 You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

$$3^x\cdot4^{2x+1}=6^{x+2}$$

$$\implies 3^x\cdot16^x\cdot4=6^x\cdot6^2$$

$$\implies\frac{3^x\cdot16^x}{6^x}=9$$

$$\implies\bigg(\frac{16}{2}\bigg)^x=9$$

$$\implies8^x=9$$

Taking log on both sides

$$\ln8^x=\ln9$$

$$\implies x=\frac{\ln9}{\ln8}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$3^x4^{2x+1}=6^{x+2}$$
$$3^x2^{4x+2}=6^{x+2}$$
$$6^x2^{3x+2}=6^{x+2}$$
$$2^{3x+2}=36$$
$$2^{3x}=9$$
$$8^x=9$$
$$x=\log_8{9}$$
$$x=\frac{\ln 9}{\ln 8}$$

Answer (score 2):

Take the logarithm of both sides, you will end up with a first degree equation:

$$x (\ln 3+2\ln 4 - \ln 6)=-\ln 4 + 2 \ln6$$

$$x \ln 8=\ln9...$$

Edit: computational error fixed

Comment: Thank very much, @GoodDeeds

Answer (score 1):

$$Log9/Log8$$
Just take all the terms with power of x on the one side and the rest on the other side..use the fact that $4^{2x}=16^x$..and combine it with $3^x$..and just arrange the terms